# How to integrate MySQL with codeblocks IDE

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

I have been searching solution for this problem whole day.Any help would make me grateful. I am using Code::blocks IDE 16.01. I want to connect from my IDE to my MySQL database server. I have tried a lot of options but yet to succeed. I have my MYSQL INSTALLER setup already and have downloaded the mysql connector and mysql server. I am gonna show you the code and the way i have already tried.

This is my simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   MYSQL* conn;
   conn = mysql_init(NULL);
   if (mysql_real_connect(conn,"localhost","root","","test",0,NULL,0) !=0)
   {
      cout << "Succesfully  Connected to MySQL database xxxx" << endl;
   }

    mysql_close(conn);

   return 0;
}
```

I have my MySQL setup in C drive and I have linked that as below

[image: Library files linking]

[image: Include foldes]

[image: Include folder]

After doing all the work I have been shown the following errors

[image: Errors shown]

Please someone help me. Thanks in advance. Please feel free to ask If you guyz need anything to know.

Comment: This looks to me like you're missing a library in your `#include` section.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. What is that? Please tell me.

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.1/include_2mysql_8h.html

Comment: @Tim In which case he would get a compilation error - he is getting a link error.

Comment: I think mysql.h file is alright. And @tim i have already read that article :'( :'(

Comment: Based on Neil's comment, then I would suggest that maybe you're missing one or more DLLs which need to be there for the MySQL connector to work.

Comment: Ohhh I am sorry.I forgot to mention that i have added the `libmysql.dll` file in the main.cpp directory and the debug directory. @Tim

Comment: I gave you an upvote, this is as much as I can do.  I don't see anything wrong with your setup.

Comment: Thats very kind of you @Tim. Please help me if you find anything for me

Comment: To use MySQL Connector in Code::Blocks, you have to compile it under GCC. Otherwise you'll get linker errors.

Comment: @NeilButterworth can you take a look please if you have time.

Comment: well I think i am doing it under GCC compiler, right? @user3366592

Comment: @Sakil I meant, you need to compile the __libraries__. These you've included are probably compiled for Visual Studio.

Comment: Ohh I see.Thats worth a try I think. @user3366592. I will let you know.

Comment: After reading the compiling manual, consider donwloading [this repository](https://github.com/hjiawei/mysql-connector-cpp). Without these files, building the libraries might be painful.

Comment: well let me check please @user3366592. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In third step of your CodeBlocks setup you must specify the lib path (and not the include path), as below:
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib` .
Then rebuilds your application.